# How to show $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \log_{2}{n} \rfloor} \bigg \lceil \frac{n}{2^{i+1}} \bigg \rceil \cdot 2i \le 2n-2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

As part of an exercise I try to conclude that:
$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \log_{2}{n} \rfloor} \bigg \lceil \frac{n}{2^{i+1}} \bigg \rceil \cdot 2i 
\le 2n-2$$

where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I tried many different ways, including using infinite/finite geometric series sum formula.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a combinatorial solution to this. Both sides seem to count something. Maybe related to this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula?

Comment: @ShBh Maybe, I'm not familiar with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given my low amount of reputation I’m unable to put this in a short comment, but the inequality is untrue for $n=9$, and is also false for infinitely many other values of $n$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks!